# How does this C++ code return 0,0,3

Tags: c++

Here is the code :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int a, b;
int f(int c)
{
    int n = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < c, i++;)
    {
        int a = n + i;                              
    }                                     
    return a;
}
void main()
{
    int i = 3;
    int b = f(i);          
    cout << a << b << i;
}
```

The output is 0,0,3

I understand the a = 0 because it is a global variable and defaults to 0, and i = 3, but I can't figure out how or why b = 0

Comment: Name your variables better and you will find out. You have two declarations of `a`, so your call to `f()` returns the global one.

Comment: `-Wall` reveals the bug as well: `weird.cpp:9:13: warning: unused variable ‘a’ [-Wunused-variable]`

Comment: you have two 'a' one global and one local to that 'for-loop' at the bottom of 'f' it returns the global 'a' that is 0

Comment: Your loop in `f` has a comma, shouldn't that be a semicolon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your program, `f()` always returns `0`. The `a` inside the `for` loop is a different `a` from the global variable (it "shadows" it). Therefore, local variable `b` in `main()` (which shadows global `b`) is initialized to `0` by the call to `f()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because in for loop of function f, a is a local varaible. Its scople is effective only in for loop. So return value is global a; So return 0;

Answer (score 0):

While others have already pointed out that you write to a local `a` in your loop, but return the global `a`, it's also worth nothing that even if you fix that, your loop will actually never enter it's body, because `i < c, i++` evaluates to `0`, which will be interpreted as `false`. (See [What does the comma operator , do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do)
.)

You need to fix your entire loop to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
{
    a = n + i;                              
}
```